# Using cqlsh with ssl in Cassandra : changing cqlshrc location

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I would like to use cqlsh with ssl. I followed the procedure recommended by the datastax documentation, and it worked well.
However, I would like to change the location of the cqlshrc file, and not place it in /myHomeDirectry/.cassandra as described in the cassandra documentation
how can this be done?
thanks for help..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by specifying the `—-cqlshrc` option and new cqlshrc file location when running cqlsh from the command line.

```
bin/cqlsh 192.168.0.1 -u aaron -p flynnL1ves --cqlshrc=../stackoverflow/cqlshrc
```

Here's a link to the docs on the Apache Cassandra site for more info: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/cqlsh.html#cqlshrc

**Edit -**

The only other way to do this, is to modify this line in `bin/cqlsh.py`:

```
# BEGIN history/config definition
HISTORY_DIR = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.cassandra'))
```

Cqlsh stores the `cqlsh_history` file in `~/.cassandra` and it also uses that `HISTORY_DIR` definition to set the default location of the cqlshrc file.  Without specifying the cqlshrc file on the command line, you'll need to override that default location by specifying the directory name(s) in the `os.path.join` above.

Note that this is definitely one of those "proceed at your own risk" moments.

Comment: Do you think that my idea can work if i put the cqlshrc file in the Cassandra directory/bin?

Comment: @SnetchBro Not without also following one of the 2 solutions I outlined above.  Cqlsh will _not_ look for `cqlshrc` in the main Cassandra dir or its `bin/` dir.